# Operate on dicts nested inside a list using a list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts, each dict has a `data` key. Each data key contains a bunch of attributes about a person, none of those attributes are mandatory:

```
persons = [
    {"Name": "John", "data": {"Age": 23, "Gender": "Male"}},
    {"Name": "Jane", "data": {"Age": 22, "Gender": "Female"}},
    {"Name": "Harry", "data": {"Age": 22}},
    {"Name": "Hermione", "data": {"Gender": "Female"}},
]
```

What I'd like to do is extract a distinct list of the Age values. I've done it like this:

```
ages = set()
persondatas = [person['data'] for person in persons]
for persondata in persondatas:
    if 'Age' in persondata:
        ages.add(persondata['Age'])
ages
```

which returns:

> {22, 23}

which is exactly what I want but I'm thinking there must be a better, neater, way than looping over a list that I obtained using a list comprehension. Can I do the required work inside a list comprehension perhaps? My first aborted attempt went like this:

`[person['data']['Age'] for person in l]`

which failed:

> KeyError: 'Age'

There must be a better way but I've fiddled around and can't work it out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a conditional into your list comprehension - knock out both operations with one loop.

```
>>> {person['data']['Age'] for person in persons if 'Age' in person['data']}
set([22, 23])
```

Notice how I use curly braces (`{}`), instead of square brackets (`[]`), to denote a [*set comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ages = set([person["data"]["Age"] for person in persons if "Age" in person["data"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is a list comprehension combined with filter.

```
set(filter(None, [p['data'].get('Age') for p in persons]))
```